# Passar IFDDatasetReference (Firedac) para o ClientDataSet.Data

Tags: delphi, firedac, tclientdataset

Tenho uma *Query* do *FireDAC* (*FDQuery*) e quero passar seu resultado para um *ClientDataSet*.

Visto o FireDAC trabalhar com **IFDDataSetReference** e o *ClientDataSet* trabalhar com **OleVariant**, da erro de compatibilidade.
Código que gera o erro:

```
  ClientDataSet1.Data := FDQuery1.Data;
```

Erro apresentado: **Invalid data packet**.

Como posso fazer isso?
Detalhes importantes:

- Tem que ser o ClientDataSet, nesse caso não pode ser FDMemTable.
- Não quero/posso percorrer a Query com um While para passar para o
  ClientDataSet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clientDataSet` tem que ter exatamente a mesma estrutura da query ?

Nesse caso você deve utilizar um componente chamado `DataSetProvider`,

Segue um exemplo de utilização :

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FDQuery1.SQL.Text := 'select * from tbClientes';
  DataSetProvider1.DataSet := FDQuery1;
  ClientDataSet1.ProviderName := DataSetProvider1;
  ClientDataSet1.Active := true; // cds que abre a query
  FDQuery1.close; //Query pode ser fechada, o clientDataSet irá armazenar os dados.
end;
```

Lembrando que utilizando um provider, o clientDataSet fica encarregado de abrir a query.

Answer (score -1):

Use query.data.

Use seuclient.data := suaquery.data, a propriedade data retorna o dataset de dados.

```
function TRegra.ListarTitulosAVencer(pInicial, pFinal: TDate): TFDQuery;
begin
  with Query do begin
    SQL.Clear;
    SQL.Add(MontaSQL(1));
    Regras.Geral.Parametro(Query, 'DataInicial', ftDate, pInicial);
    Regras.Geral.Parametro(Query, 'DataFinal', ftDate, pFinal);
    Open;
    result := Query;
  end;
end;
```

Para usar utilizo

```
var vRegra: TRegra;
begin
  inherited;
  vRegra := TRegra.Create;
  dsGrid.DataSet := nil;
  MemGrid.Data := vRegra.ListarTitulosAVencer(Inicial, Final).Data;
  dsGrid.Dataset := MemGrid;
  FreeAndNil(vRegra);
end;
```

Comment: Como mencionei na pergunta, já faço isso e é isso que gera o erro. De qualquer forma, obrigado por tentar ajudar.